# Powershell IComparable errors when foreach looping through an array of SQL data

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm creating an array with the following:

`$QueryResults = QuerySQL -SQLInstance $Instance -SQLQuery $Query -SQLDatabase PI | select PercentDiff | format-table -HideTableHeaders`

It contains:

0.36
0.47
0.89

The following foreach loop is throwing the below error:

```
    if ($row -lt 1 -And $row -gt -1) {
        $over1Percent = "False"}
    else {
        $over1Percent = "True"}
        break
    }
```

*Cannot compare "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData" because it is not IComparable.*

I can't work out why this is occurring, would anyone be able to help me out? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The output from `Format-Table` is only good for one thing: *presenting data to the user*  - it's absolutely useless for *operating* on the underlying data from which it was generated.

If you want just the 3 `PercentDiff` values, change your query pipeline to:

```
$QueryResults = QuerySQL -SQLInstance $Instance -SQLQuery $Query -SQLDatabase PI | Select -ExpandProperty PercentDiff
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! PercentDiff is not a property here but rather a column pulled from the SQL Query - hence ExpandProperty ends in error

Comment: @Inorthern _what_ error? I'm not psychic, I can't see your screen :-)

Comment: Hey just closing this thread off, I decided to output the results to three separate variables and converted them to decimal.

Comment: @Inorthern great, you should post an answer then :)